# setState not updated immediately makes formik initialValues undefined

Tags: reactjs, use-state, formik, setstate

here is my code:

```
const getSystemProfile = async () => {
    try {
          const res = await API.get("/sys/");
          console.log(res.data)
          setPreferencesData(res.data)
    } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
          toast.error("Unexpected server error");
    }
      
    
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getSystemProfile();
    }, []);
        
    const formik = useFormik({
    
    enableReinitialize: true,
    initialValues: {
       qrndMaxNumberOfFiles: preferencesData[3].value || "",
    },
    validateOnChange: true,
    validateOnBlur: true,
    // validate,
    
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      // validateForm(values);
      //console.log("onSubmit: " + values)
      // new_update(values);
      // resetForm()
    },
});
```

will get:
**TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating `preferencesData[3].value`)**

I know I got this error because `setState` does not update the value immediately.
but how can I solve the problem if I need to use it with the formik?
thank you

Comment: You can use optional chaining to avoid this errors.  !!preferencesData[3] && preferencesData[3]?.value') .Cause it have side effect, it will update the state when api call is done and re render the component. To avoid crash you can use optional chaining and UI loaders

Comment: thank you Harish, could you please make an example ?